# Simple image uploading with collection fs

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

I have installed collection fs package to process my image uploads and so far,i have not uploaded a single image successfully.

I have this code in my event

```
'change .ip': function(event, template) {
       FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
           var yourFile = new FS.File(file);
        SchoolImages.insert(yourFile, function (err, fileObj) {
          if (err){
             // handle error
             alert('error');

          } else {
             // handle success depending what you need to d
             alert('success');
          }
        });
     });
  }
```

This is my html

```
<input type="file" class="ip form-control" name="sn_edit" value="">
```

This is my collections code

```
SchoolImages = new FS.Collection("SchoolImages", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("SchoolImages", {path: "~/meteor_uploads"})]
});


if (Meteor.isServer) {
  SchoolImages.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
      return false;
    },

    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
      return false;
    },

    remove: function (userId, doc) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  SchoolImages.deny({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
      return true;
    },

    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
      return true;
    },

    remove: function (userId, doc) {
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

When i try uploading an image,no image is uploaded and no collection is created. My code gives an error  `alert('error')` - see the code above.

How should i rectify my code to upload an image successfully?.

Comment: If You're interested with uploading to `gridfs` I recommend my article: http://mrmnmly.net/posts/saving-images-from-api-in-meteor-apps

Comment: @lukaszkups I have read the tutorial but its too complex since i am getting a file from the computer and not fro the Api. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to allow db operation inside in Meteor.isServer. You can directly write the collections code as follow.

---

```
SchoolImages = new FS.Collection("SchoolImages", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("SchoolImages", {path: "~/meteor_uploads"})]
});



SchoolImages.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
      return true;
    },

    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
      return true;
    },

    remove: function (userId, doc) {
      return true;
    }
  });
```

Generally I recommend to write this code inside the lib folder when you structure your project in different folders.

Comment: Its strange,its iron cli that puts it there inside is server. I moved the code and still no change.

Comment: That's always work for me, If you can share min code on github that I would like to help you more.

Comment: This is the gist of my entire code https://gist.github.com/openqubit/3fd44a259f500b6e6c30526e637d83ef